# Como puedo generar el siguiente cogido en SQLSERVER cuando inserto un dato?

Tags: sql-server

Quiero registrar datos de solicitudes en una tabla, sin embargo me pidieron que generara un código único para la solicitud y que llevara la estructura que muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no tengo absolutamente ninguna idea de como hacerlo, si alguien puede ayudarme le agradecería mucho.
Estoy trabajando con SQLSERVER2014

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacerlo en 2 pasos.

Primero añadir el registro, pero sin añadir al campo IDSolicitud.

```
INSERT INTO X (...) VALUES (...)
```

Despues actualizar el campo para ese registro

```
UPDATE X SET IDSolicitud=CONCAT('SAC-',SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'-',YEAR(getdate()) WHERE id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: pero podría hacer directamente el Insert con CONCAT('SAC-',(select count(*) from NOMBRE_TABLA)+1,'-',YEAR(getdate()) ¿o me equivoco?

Comment: No, porque ya no tendría porque ser autoincrementable. Es decir, si borras registros, el autoincremento sigue, pero el Count no.

Comment: correcto, no me daba cuenta de ese detalle

Comment: Que pasa cuando cambias de año? debe reiniciarse el contador por año? creo que deberías tomar en cuenta eso.

Comment: gracias por responder, en la sentencia antes mostrada por Aritz , el id que está despues del WHERE a que se refiere?

Comment: Es para actualizar el campo de IDSolicitud del registro creado anteriormente